# ImportError: cannot import name 'TwitterRestPager' from 'TwitterAPI' (C:\Users\My name \Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\TwitterAPI\__init__.py)

Tags: python, api, twitter

I'm trying to import `TwitterRestPager`, but keep getting the error:

```
"cannot import name 'TwitterRestPager' from 'TwitterAPI' (C:\Users\My 
name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\TwitterAPI\__init__.py) "
```

--  (the My Name in the file path is my actual name just replaced for  privacy purposes)

I already updated both requests and `TwitterApi`.

Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
! pip install TwitterAPI
! pip install TwitterAPI --upgrade
from TwitterAPI import TwitterRestPager
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use TwitterPager instead. It looks like TwitterRestPager is depreciated in the newer version (available in TwitterAPI 2.4.1 https://pydoc.net/TwitterAPI/2.4.1/TwitterAPI.TwitterRestPager/)

Answer (score -1):

Check the site packages if the TwitterRestPager is in it. If it is not, and pip is not properly installing it, try to find the script or file online, and download it to the directory from which it is being imported from.